# Why a subselect filter fails after a columnstore index deploy?

Tags: sql, sql-server, columnstore

I deployed a columnstore index on a huge table, the all together perfomance gain was significant, but a report that has where id in (subselect) filtering started to fail with datatype mismatch. I checked out the datatypes and the error message does not make any sense. When I rolled back the new index the query ran without any error. Played around with it a bit and figured out if I flip the where -subselect into a join with string_split it works with the index.

Have you ever experienced something similar?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably you were lucky to not encounter the data type issue before, adding the index likely changed the execution plan and pushed the comparision further down where it encountered the issue. There are workarounds but you'd need to provide more info,

Comment: thanks for the comment, what info would you need?

Comment: hi @Tom, First we need the Execution Plan (the XML and not just screenshot), and we need to be able to reproduce the scenario. So please provide queries to create the relevant table and indexes and to insert some sample data. Finally we need the exact query which you try to execute

Comment: Could we talk about this in general please? Like possible pitfalls, possible workarounds? To reproduce a workable scenario might take a lot of effort.
Thanks!

Comment: Upload the execution plan to [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question. I agree with @Stu the most likely cause is the query includes an unsafe conversion (probably implict) which was an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned in the comments, you must be doing in implicit convert somewhere in your data causing the issue. Need to explicitly cast the data and handle the exceptions accordingly

```
/*Raw data*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Test
CREATE TABLE #Test (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Val Varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('1'),('2'),('A')

/*Example of how index might "break" code aka expose implicit conversion issue*/

/*This select works*/
CREATE INDEX ix on #Test(Val)
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM #Test WITH (INDEX (ix)) WHERE Val = 2 /*Implicitly casts Val to int*/

/*Change index and run same query, it now tries to cast 'A' and breaks*/
CREATE INDEX ix on #Test(Val DESC) WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON )
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM #Test WITH (INDEX (ix)) WHERE Val = 2
```

### Possible Solutions

```
/*Need to explicitly cast so data types match*/
/*Can cast the search parameter (generally most performant as it allows use of indexes on source data)*/
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM #Test WHERE Val = Cast(2 AS Varchar(100)) /*Explicitly cast the parameter*/

/*Or use TRY_CAST to cast the source data. Might be needed if you have formatted data in the Val column*/
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM #Test WHERE TRY_CAST(Val AS INT) = 2
```